# How to find average consecutive positive number in excel?

Tags: excel, function, average

[image]

Hi all,

I want to find the average consecutive positive number from row 12 to row 31. Is there any way to calculate it without extra column D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Frequency:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(C12:C32>0,ROW(C12:C32)),IF(C12:C32>0,"",ROW(C12:C32)))>0,FREQUENCY(IF(C12:C32>0,ROW(C12:C32)),IF(C12:C32>0,"",ROW(C12:C32)))))
```

Depending on one's version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]